# Join but only get once with newest date

Tags: mysql

i have data like this.
Table `customer`

```
| customerId | fullName     | sex
| 1          | Budi Arsana  | Male
| 2          | Peter Parker | Male
```

and other table name `transaction`

```
| Id | bookingDate | customer
| 1  | 2011-09-01  | 1
| 2  | 2011-09-30  | 1
| 3  | 2011-09-01  | 2
```

And i want get result with combined that 2 table which select the customer who has the transaction then get only 1 transaction with the latest date. Like this

```
| customerId | fullName     | sex  | transId | bookingDate
| 1          | Budi Arsana  | Male | 2       | 2011-09-30
| 2          | Peter Parker | Male | 3       | 2011-09-01
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT c.customerId, c.fullName, c.sex, t.Id AS transId, t.bookingDate
    FROM customer c
        INNER JOIN (SELECT customer, MAX(bookingDate) AS MaxDate
                        FROM transaction
                        GROUP BY customer) q
            ON c.customerId = q.customer
        INNER JOIN transaction t
            ON q.customer = t.customer
                 AND q.MaxDate = t.bookingDate;
```

Comment: can i know what the mean of the 2nd line? `FROM customer c`, Did you mean `FROM customer AS c`?

Comment: @GusDeCooL The `AS` is optional, so both versions mean the same thing.

Comment: Yep, it's the short form, `AS` can be omitted. I wouldn't recommend it though, at least when it's used for aliases of columns. It's easy to miss putting in a comma, but not so easy to find out you've missed it when you debug. I.e. `SELECT id group, name FROM users` could be tricky to find. Putting and `AS` requires just a few more keystrokes, but makes it much easier to read IMHO

Comment: @Nikoloff As you can see in my answer, I take a mixed approach. I use the `AS` when aliasing columns for the reasons you specified, but generally omit it after table names since the association is more obvious in that case.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli, agreed, that's why I clarified I'm talking about columns, not tables :)

Comment: thank you joe & nikoloff. i didn't know if its the other way use `AS` :)

Answer (score 2):

Using a self-exclusion join:

```
SELECT c.customerId, c.fullName, c.sex, t.Id AS transId, t.bookingDate
  FROM customer c
       LEFT JOIN transaction t ON t.customer = c.customerId
       LEFT JOIN transaction t2 ON t2.customer = t.customer
   AND t2.bookingDate > t.bookingDate 
 WHERE t2.Id IS NULL;
```

The principle is that you create another join to a working copy of the `transaction` table (`t2`) and use that to eliminate from the final resultset all but the most recent record in `transaction` (`t`).

Caveat: This will not work if you have multiple bookings per day per customer. In that case you might want to change from date to timestamp.

Comment: +1 Works beautifully if you remove the extra `t` in `transaction t t2` in your second `LEFT JOIN`: http://sqlize.com/MpaCjlZb67

Comment: Ah yes, thank you @mella. Edited. And thanks for the tip about sqlize. Hadn't seen that before.